# how to get a drop down list to work in mobiles

Tags: html, anchor, html-select

I am building my first website and am trying to make it responsive. I am using a html list as the menu and for the links. When I test it on an opera software tester. It doesn't work properly. I don't know of any other tester devices.
The problem that I have is that when I click on a link it always displays the site map page. None of the other links will display.

The html code that i use is below;

```
<div id="drop-down">
  <form name="form">
     <SELECT name="guidelinks" onChange="window.location=document.form.guidelinks.options[document.form.guidelinks.selectedIndex].value"> 
<option selected>Main Menu</option>
<option value="index.html">Home Page</option>
<option value="small-books.html">Free books to download</option>
<option value="contact.html">Contact Us</option>
<option value="sitemap.html">Site map</option>
<option value="Free-studies-to-download.html#study-3">- Study -Reconciliation</option>
</select>
</form>
```

There is a close div at the end. Doesn't show in code.

It also seems that the sub menus don't work. They are anchors. The page just refreshes in mobile devices. I understand that some mobile browsers block them.

Is there a way to get the list to work?